# Combine Laptop Chargers From More Watts

Tags: laptop, power-supply, charging

I am on vacation and my G73JH's laptop charger smoked and failed. So I went to OfficeMax and grabbed a travel charger but it only puts out 90 watts which is no where near the 140 watts my laptop needs to run. Luckily it will still power on but the battery won't charge and any heavy use causes a sudden shutdown.

I am wondering if it would be possible to purchase a second travel charger and wire it in parallel with the first theoretically upping the wattage to 180 watts?

For reference here is the travel charger [OfficeMax (the only local computer supply store) carries](http://www.officemax.com/technology/computer-accessories/laptop-chargers/product-prod4060788)

Comment: I have trouble believing there's an OfficeMax in town, but no mom-n-pop computer shop that can order you an appropriate AC adapter within a day or two.  Where are you, OfficeMaxVille, USA? :)

Comment: `the 140 watts my laptop needs to run`   Really‽ `ఠ_ఠ` Is this normal/common? My *desktop* computer tops out at ~110W. The whole point (well, one of the main points) to using a laptop is their low power requirement.

Comment: @Synetech I know the G73JH is kind of a beast, it's not really normal at all. The 17" screen 1st gen i7 and ATI graphics card are all horribly inefficient.

Comment: @techie007 Yeah there are a few mom-n-pop stores but I am only here for 4 more days so there is a good chance I would be gone before they got it.

Comment: @user1149651 - might be a shot in the dark, but if you at a hotel, check the lost and found. I have done that and they usually have a bunch of chargers that get left behind. Happy hunting. And would you really trust splicing together two power packs with your i7 lappy?

Comment: @CarlB That's actually a good idea I will check it out. And no I would not unless someone much smarter than me said it was OK but looks like I am out of luck on that front.

Comment: @user1149651 - if your in an area that has three of four hotels, check them all. Pick up some free stuff! ;)

Comment: You can also try hitting a Radio Shack since they carry variable output DC adapters.  I feel your pain.  My Toshiba A75 uses a 120w.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to the charging, some laptops will not charge if it is not a charger designed for that laptop; your laptop might be one of these.  We had a dell like this; it had charging problems; I installed a dell program and then immediately put up a message saying a non-dell charger was being used and the computer would stay powered but the battery would not charge.

As to wiring two chargers in parallel, you can do it, but it can work.  If both power supplies are exactly equal, in a perfect world, it would work.  The problem arises when there are not equal.  Slight voltage difference, slight frequency differences from circuitry in the power supply and turns in the transformers make output signals that do not match.  BUT, if you use diodes to isolate on from the other and you can get voltages to match up, it should work.  http://www.codemsys.com/SMPS/Parallel.htm.

Granted, I am guessing you were hoping for a simple wire them together and Voila, more power! :).  Point is, you can wire them together and hobbyists do all the time.  But there are ways that work, and there are ways that don't.

Comment: You can pick up two Schottky barrier diodes at Radio Shack. Make sure they're rated for at least the current and voltage one power supply puts out or they may overheat.

Comment: That's much more what I was looking for! I am pretty comfortable with basic circuitry/wiring so I think I'll head to Radioshack and give it a shot. My only concern is the part about trimming the voltages in your link. I assume the chargers will be close in voltage but could a 100 MV or so difference cause significant problems?

Comment: It will draw more current from the higher voltage transformer creating unbalanced current draw.  100mv should not cause huge problems, but I'm no expert.  Power supply's voltages vary with current.  The higher the current, the lower the voltage.  As more current is drawn from the higher voltage PS, the voltage drops towards the lower voltage PS and the current from the lower voltage PS increases.  Goodwill in nicer areas is a great place for PS if your not buying a proper OEM one, and are simply looking for voltage and current.  Granted, they may not have what you need, but its worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

No, If you were to splice one into the other, only one would work.  Remember electricity follows the path of least resistance.

Comment: Right, and the electricity from each power supply would follow the path of least resistance -- through the laptop. If you were right, you couldn't [wire power sources in parallel](http://www.zbattery.com/Connecting-Batteries-in-Series-or-Parallel) to increase the capacity but keep the voltage the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try leaving the laptop off with it plugged in, it might charge slowly.  I'd keep an eye on how warm the powersupply is getting.  If it gets hot unplug it and stop attempting to charge the battery with the under powered power supply.

Comment: Good idea and all, but how does this answer the question asked?

Comment: It makes the suggestion to charge the laptop without issue when not in use and run it off the battery. It may be a little inconvenient, but at least it makes sense and would work until the OP can get a proper adapter.

Comment: @zimmer62 Thanks for the suggestion but I already tried it and no dice. Even left it off and plugged in overnight but all I got was a blinking orange battery light (think it means error while charging).